# Parse.com-FindAsync doesn't work.Not able to get Top 10 score

Tags: loops, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, c#-2.0

I work in unity and I am using parse.com to save my game score.But I'm getting a problem that I'm not able to get top ten score. Here the following code I'm using,

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("GameScore").OrderByDescending("score").Limit(5);
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {

        IEnumerable<ParseObject> comments = t.Result;

        foreach (var obj in comments) {
            int score = obj.Get<int>("score");
            Debug.Log(score);
            string playerName = obj.Get<string>("playerName");
            Debug.Log(playerName);
            bool cheatMode = obj.Get<bool>("cheatMode");
            Debug.Log("cheatmode"+cheatMode);
        }
    });
```

when I run this code  the "foreach" loop runs only once, But I have save six rows in my class(over the parse.com server side).
I don't know why it is not responding. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: remove limit clause from query and then then use for loop from 0 -> 5 to get your result.